# Managing an NSManagedObject change between views

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

At the moment I am passing my `NSManagedObjects` via `Segues` to child views.

I am yet to make a change to any of these `NSManagedObjects` but it occurred to me that I may be going about it in the wrong way.

When I make a change to an `NSManagedObject` in this way and save it back to the `MOC` and then I return to a parent view - will that parent views' `NSManagedObject` have those changes or do I need to make a new `fetchRequest` to the `MOC` with every view load?

Comment: Please don't add objective-c tags to swift related questions

Comment: i would also recommend to passing the related NSManagedObject via seques. And yes the changes will also appear in the parent view, because the NSManagedObject is in both viewcontrollers the same. But you need to check for changes for the object maybe with a KVO in the parent view controller.

Comment: @Jasper There is nothing in the question related specifically to swift.  There are far more Core Data related programs using ObjectiveC than swift.  Thus, there is no reason to edit the tag placed by the original poster.

Comment: You are right, my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the object if you like, because you can just ask it for its MOC if you need it.

Or, you can pass the MOC itself.

If the views share the same MOC, then yes, they will see the same data.

Or, you can create an independent MOC, which will keep any changes isolated to that MOC until it is saved.  Then, if you choose to save to "detail MOC", those changes can be merged in the typical Core Data way, or if your new MOC is a child context, the changes will automatically be saved into the parent MOC.

As I said in my comment to the earlier post.  Please do not stuff a managedObjectContext into the App Delegate.  Yes, that's how Apple's template works.  It's completely wrong.  The only benefit is that it's simple.

It's still wrong though.

What you said you were doing is the correct approach.

Comment: out of interest, how do you ask an object for its moc?

Comment: @JodyHagins - I am really happy to have read your answer as well. I have learned something today! Can you provide any information about what makes using the appDelegate incorrect? I am trying to understand the implications of that method as I've used it before. Thanks!

Comment: @Charlie - Lots of reasons.  One of the main reasons, however, is the Single Responsibility Principle.  See this link: http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/srp.pdf  Also, while my stack is a bit different from Marcus', here is a good paper on how to handle a core data stack: http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/03/core-data-stack/

Comment: @JodyHagins - thanks for that info! The learning never ends, haha.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**
In response to the comments on other answers and below, I did some more research about this topic. I am really confused that the apple docs lead me to believe this was correct. I am unsure of why it is not really correct, but it appears that many people view it as not the right way to do it. As such, I am leaving this answer posted for people to refer to. This is a functioning way of doing this, but it is not preferred by people who know more about the topic than I.

It is confusing to find many references to accomplishing this the way I have described on SO... it lead me further to believe this was the way to do it. Maybe someone can post useful links as to details of the preferred method?

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

I have found it is much easier to have the view controllers reference the appDelegate to get the NSManagedObject and the NSManagedObjectContext. This prevents you from passing that info over and over again, and ensures that you are always referring to the same MOC.

To do this, you would have this listed on each view controller that needs the MOC:

You can do it like this:

```
let appDel : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

var moc = appDel.managedObjectContext!
```

or you could say:

```
var moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
```

Comment: awesome, i was just reading up... I am already doing this... but what about when I want to pass an object to a child view? at the minute i am doing it like follows:

managedObject = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? NSManagedObject

but I have read that it is better to use the id, then how do i retrieve that object using its ID in the child view?

Comment: You could either pass the defining characteristics of the object to the next controller, or pass an instance of that object itself to the next controller.

Let’s say you have an object [Place] that has name, date, time. You can save the fetchResult of the MOC to that a variable aPlace:  let sortedFetchResults = moc.executeFetchRequest(sortedFetchRequest, error: nil) as! [Place]

You just need to make sure you only get the one object. 

Otherwise, you can pass whatever your “where” clause would be to the next view controller and have it ask the MOC for the object itself using NSPredicate.

Comment: I prefer to find the one object that I'm interested in, cast it as the proper type of object (var mocobject =  as! Place), and then pass it to the next view controller itself using segueWithIdentifier: and setting the next view controllers class variable before segue.

Comment: i think thats what im already doing, my segue is like this: if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? JobViewController {
                
                destination.workItem = sender as? Work
            
            }and in the child controller I can access that work object, if i make a change to it though and save it to the moc will the parents moc update?

Comment: There isn't really a way to get the ID of the object in the MOC. There is no default ID assigned and incremented for reference. Here is an example of my segue stuff if that helps:

in prepareForSegue:
        if segue.identifier == "freqdetails" {
            let freqVC = segue.destinationViewController as! FreqTableVC
            freqVC.freqArr = freqArray //this is the variable on the other controller being set to the local variable freqArray
        }
    }

Comment: and the fregArray contains your NSManagedObjects or certain properties of them etc.? ok, i think im on the right lines...

Comment: Yeah in that example, the view set freqArray to the right object that I wanted passed. It could be freqString for all that it cares (if you wanted to pass only a string). It is just the correct object I want passed. Then, when the segue is called, the prepareforsegue: method finds out what view is being segue'd to. It then updates upcoming view's class variable to that if it meets the requirements of that if statement.

Comment: Good! If I've answered the question for you, don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Comment: can't recommend this solution. You are using the AppDelegate as an Singleton. I recommend to take a look at MagicalRecord and how there are the different context's handled.

Comment: @CarlJ - is the concern  that if a same entity is modified in two different places, you have to manage the merge conflict? I've been using this method with a trump policy in the coredata stack that favors the on memory data, and I've never had an issue... wondering the downside.

Comment: @Charlie: that isn't the problem, but in my personal opinion the AppDelegate shouldn't be used to have some sort of singleton where you can store your data an access it from every where. I really hate it if i open a project and the AppDelegate have several hunderd/thousand lines of code. Honestly the AppDelegate shouldn't be more than 150 lines of code. To sum this up: its only a codestylguide concept.

Comment: @CarlJ - Understandable. Aside from the CoreData stack I haven't actually used the appDel for much other than normal stuff like entering and exit foreground etc. I think all of Ubiquitous Container CoreData code adds about 1/4 of a mouse scroll :P haha. I get confused just thinking about managing multiple mocs.

Comment: This is a horrible idea.  Unfortunately, it continues to be propagated because it is easy... at least in the sort run.  The AppDelegate is a delegate to the Application... not a dumping ground for objects.  This approach is generally unsound, and should be avoided at all costs.